# О сортировке меток вопроса

Tags: обсуждение, метки

Вопрос мой появился по мотивам [вот этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/597972) поста.

Изначально в вопросе было две метки: ssh и git. При этом я их ввёл именно в этом порядке и ожидал увидеть именно в этом же порядке, но они отсортировались по другому признаку -- тогда я подумал, что это похоже на алфавитную сортировку.

Мысленно я разделял метки на "основная метка" и "вспомогательная ветка": изначально мне казалось, что вопрос про ssh, гит же здесь не особо играет роль (так и оказалось в итоге).

Хорошо ли то, что метки отсортированы? Может быть имеет смысл их оставить в том же порядке, как они введены автором вопроса? У кого есть какое мнение на этот счёт? Хочу понять: толи это я белая ворона и не так пользуюсь so, как задумано - толи есть возможность улучшить поведение сайта.

PS Метки сортируются видимо по популярности тега: чем больше вопросов по тегу задано -- тем выше его вес. По крайней мере, когда оказалось, что это вопрос не про гит, а на грани ssh и ansible -- метки выстроились в таком порядке: git, ssh, ansible.

Comment: [Метки сортируются по популярности](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/50819/339911). Пересортировка может произойти в том числе при правке вопроса (при добавлении/удалении меток).

Comment: Согласен, сортировать не надо (иначе возникают проблемы с задумкой автора)

Comment: @avp какие проблемы? Порядок меток по сути не влияет ни на что. Кроме визуального отображения.

Comment: @alexolut, не знаю, кто как, а я обычно первые 2-3 воспринимаю

Comment: @avp их по сути вообще не надо воспринимать *вручную*. Формируем "избранное" и готово.

Comment: @alexolut, не, мне так не нравится. Я просто главную страницу просматриваю.

Comment: @avp при этом, если попадаются вопросы с метками из "избранного" - они подсвечиваются. Так что ничто не мешает просматривать страницу как и раньше, но при этом не обращая внимания на метки вовсе.

Comment: @alexolut, и все же, если автор решил, что порядок меток отражает его виденье проблемы, то может лучше их не сортировать? А нынешний подход к сорировке -- он же совершенно не интуитивный и вообще ничего не дает. Если кто-то решит вдруг узнать какие метки популярней, так он зайдет в список меток.

Comment: @avp так 2-3 и нужны, когда на вопросе пять меток, обычно от двух можно было бы и отказаться.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, согласитесь, что метки вопроса о базах данных для linux и windows будут упорядочены, ну *странновато* -- `linux` `база-данных` `windows`

Comment: @avp соглашусь, главное в таком наборе — база данных.